# R table function apply all columns

Tags: r, output, distribution, target

I want to apply table function in R to all my columns.

I want to see the distribution of my TARGET and ALL OTHER COLUMNS. Here is an exmaple:

```
table(df$target, df$variable1)
```

I have 500 columns. How can I do that for all my 500 columns?

```
table(df$target, df$variable1),
table(df$target, df$variable2),
table(df$target, df$variable3)
```

without writing one by one? (with apply?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `lapply` to loop over the column names other than the 'target' with `setdiff` (assuming we need all other columns), then get the `table` of the 'target' and the column looped returning a `list` of frequency tables

```
outlst <- lapply(setdiff(names(df), 'target'), 
      function(nm) table(df$target, df[[nm]]))
```

Comment: ı want to ask something, in this code it does not show the name of  "variables" in the results. it just gives numbers. is it possible to set the variable names also?

Comment: @determinator An option is to name the list with `names(outlst) <- setdiff(names(df), 'target')`